# How to check whether the particular text present in GridHyperLink's NavigateUrl, when the user clicks on the link?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, forms, telerik

I have a hyper link in the grid like below

```
`<telerik:GridHyperLinkColumn HeaderText="Website Link" DataTextField="LinkAddress" DataTextFormatString="{0}" DataNavigateUrlFields="LinkAddress" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="{0}"
                    ItemStyle-VerticalAlign="Top" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" HeaderStyle-Font-Size="Small" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="Black" Target="_blank" >`
```

Now when the user clicks on the link in the grid (on the screen), I should check whether the link contains the text "http://" or not , if not I should add that text before the link (dynamically ) in my aspx page (using javascript) and then redirect to that webaddress.

Now how to achieve this, could anyone help me, Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do this. I would do it in the code behind in the grids ItemDataBound event so you don't have to call a javascript function.

```
Private Sub grid_ItemDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridItemEventArgs)
    If TypeOf e.Item Is GridDataItem Then
        Dim item As GridDataItem = DirectCast(e.Item, GridDataItem)
        Dim link As HyperLink = DirectCast(item("ColumnUniqueName").Controls(0), HyperLink)
        Dim sOldNavigateUrl as String = link.NavigateUrl
        If Not ((sOldNavigateUrl.Contains("http://") Or sOldNavigateUrl.Contains("https://")) Then
            link.NavigateUrl = "http://" & sOldNavigateUrl
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```